# getting null url on page controller dd4t 2.8 setup

Tags: dd4t

Hi am tying to setup dd4t 2.8 mvc5 with visual studio 2015 framework 4.6.1
using this document facing issues.

> https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/wiki/1.0-Getting-started-with-.NET

i am able to hit the page controller

> public override ActionResult Page(string url)

and getting null value in url. kindly suggest me what is the issue.

but page is getting returned with default page eg: index.aspx

> return base.Page(url);

which is working fine then it gives error on @Html.RenderComponentPresentations()

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: actionName

```
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   at DD4T.Mvc.Html.DefaultComponentPresentationRenderer.RenderComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation cp, HtmlHelper htmlHelper) in C:\projects\dd4t-mvc\source\dd4t.mvc\html\DefaultComponentPresentationRenderer.cs:line 135
   at DD4T.Mvc.Html.DefaultComponentPresentationRenderer.ComponentPresentations(IPage tridionPage, HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String[] includeComponentTemplate, String includeSchema) in C:\projects\dd4t-mvc\source\dd4t.mvc\html\DefaultComponentPresentationRenderer.cs:line 66
   at DD4T.Mvc.Html.TridionHelper.RenderComponentPresentations(HtmlHelper helper, String[] byComponentTemplate, String bySchema, IComponentPresentationRenderer renderer) in C:\projects\dd4t-mvc\source\dd4t.mvc\html\TridionHelper.cs:line 115
   at ASP._Page_Views_Page_Default_cshtml.Execute() in C:\websites\dd4tmvcdemo\dd4t2demomeyank\dd4t2demomeyank\Views\Page\Default.cshtml:line 24
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: it seems issue in some of the component presentation, where action name is expected on Component template.

Comment: i have given action name in  PT and CT

Comment: is controller name also given?

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue ? I have also asked similar question and facing the same issue. http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14322/dd4t-2-404-error

Comment: Please share how you resolved this issue!